# "Python: Select Linter" option is missing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VS Code is missing "Python: Select Linter" option when trying to run a command (F1 or Ctrl/CMD+Shift+P). Previously, (2 days ago) this option was available. Is there a way to restore this option or is there a new alternative?

I have tried creating new VS Code profile and installing just Python extension - still no mentioned option.

Comment: you should rollback the changes to the question and post your solution as answer

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski It's not a definitive answer. There should be a way to do the same with newer version of extension.

Comment: Does not matter. It's solution you successful applied. If there's anything better then it does not block others to add own answer or comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolling back Python extension to previous version (v2023.16.0) restores the option.